# editing an image - different colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i'm looking to edit this image so that 1) the picture (not the frame) becomes squared shaped 2) make the top white part larger

for 1), I tried the following but having a problem with frame color (see red circle, doesn't look natural)

[image]

for 2) tried copy pasting here too, but having the same color problem (see red cirlcle)

[image]

Is there a fix for this problem?

Here's original image

[image]

Comment: Look up how to use Adobe's Content Aware Scale, cut the photo out to a separate layer, and then do your resizing.  I have to run for tonight, but if someone else doesn't post a how-to, I will in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular image, there is a quick and dirty method. Because the object is rectangular and pretty low resolution, you can just scale the image non-proportionally.

- Make a duplicate of the layer with the image.
- Select the top layer.
- With *Rectangular Marquee Tool* select the upper part of the frame, press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag it a little taller.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the transformation.
- Now select the lower part of the image, press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag it to the desired format.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the transformation.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect.
- Use *Quick Selection Tool* to select the image. (You probably need to refine this a little or make the selection in some other way.)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to select the inverse.
- In the *Layers* panel press *Add layer mask* to make a hole for the image behind.
- With *Move Tool* drag the top layer to create the desired crop.
- Use *Crop Tool* to crop the image.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the crop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the edges of the original Polaroid frame do not have some special value you maybe can draw your own frame. Cut the wanted piece of the photo and have it as your top layer. Draw the rest with shapes, sizes and colors that you like. The next is an example of a redrawn non-photo parts:

[image]

The PSD image can be seen here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouapjj0vkr8gbel/NewFrame.psd?dl=0